# Cracking license plate checksum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, puzzle

Suppose a city has license plates assigned to cars with 7 digits $a_1$ to $a_7$ and a checksum calculated by the following algorithm: ($m_k$ are integers)
$$m_1a_1+m_2a_2+\cdots+m_7a_7\mod 28$$
(which is then encoded as an alphanumeric character)

The city administration keeps secret $m_1$ to $m_7$.

Given many different license plates, how do I create an algorithm equivalent to this?

Comment: You might not be able to get the actual values of $m_1$ to $m_7$, but you may still be able to calculate the checksum for all possible inputs $a_1$ to $a_7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 7 different license plates such that, when you form the matrix $A = (a_{ij})$ whose rows correspond to license plates, $\rm{det}(A)$ is relatively prime to $28$.

Then let $m$ be a column vector whose $i$th entry is $m_i$, and place the checksums corresponding to each plate in another column vector $x$, so that we have:

$$
A m \equiv x \pmod{28}
$$
Then in the matrix ring $\mathbb{M}_7(\mathbb{Z}/28\mathbb{Z})$, $A$ is invertible, so we can compute $m \pmod{28}$:
$$
m \equiv A^{-1} x \pmod{28}
$$

Comment: How to know that the condition guarantees that the matrix is invertible?

Comment: @user1537366: if $\det(A)$ is relatively prime to $28$, there exists $k$ such that $\det(A)\cdot k = 1\bmod{28}$. Consider the matrix $B = k\times \operatorname{adj}(A)$, where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ is the adjugate matrix of $A$, i.e., the transpose of the matrix of cofactors. Then it is routine to check that $BA=1\bmod{28}$, as $\operatorname{adj}(A)A=\det(A)\times 1$, so $BA=k\det(A)\times 1 = 1\bmod{28}$.

Answer (score 1):

What the city administration hides is a group homomorphism $f\colon (\mathbb Z/28\mathbb Z)^7\rightarrow \mathbb Z/28\mathbb Z$, that is given by $f(a_1,\dots,a_7) = m_1a_1+\dots+m_7a_7$. Note that $(\mathbb Z/28\mathbb Z)^7$ has generating families of size $7$. This means that given seven linearly independent elements (over $\mathbb Z/28\mathbb Z$) of this module, say $a^1,\dots,a^7$ (which are all $7$-elements tuples), we can generate all the other elements by taking linear combinations. For example, the family $\{(1,0,0,0,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0,0,0),(0,0,1,0,0,0,0),(0,0,0,1,0,0,0),(0,0,0,0,1,0,0),(0,0,0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,0,0,0,1)\}$ generates the module.

Thus, if we want to know the value $f(b_1,\ldots,b_7)$, we know that $b=\sum_{i=1}^7 \lambda_i a^i$ for some $\lambda_i\in\mathbb Z$, and then by linearity $f(b)=\sum_{i=1}^7\lambda_i f(a^i)$. Therefore, if you look at the cars and find seven plates which are linearly independent as elements of $(\mathbb Z/28\mathbb Z)^7$, you can determine the checksum for all the possible plates.

Comment: I thought to say $M=(\mathbb{Z}/26\mathbb{Z})^7$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank 7, we need to find a basis $m_1,\dots,m_k$ s.t. $M=\mathbb{Z}m_1\oplus\mathbb{Z}m_2\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}m_k$ and $\text{Ann}(m_i)=\{0\}$?

Comment: Woops, $M$ is a free $\mathbb Z/28\mathbb Z$ module, you are right. But anyway, the only point that is used here is that we have a small generating family, we don't care whether this family is free or not!